Framer motion Stagger Children animate whole list in once not separately
JSX
<motion.div
          variants={boxVariant}
          animate="visible"
          initial="hidden"
          className="flex flex-col gap-4 overflow-auto h-[25rem] no-scrollbar"
        >
          <AnimatePresence>
            {todos?.map((i, index) => {
              return (
                <motion.li
                  variants={listVariant}
                  exit={{ scale: 1.1, x: 500, opacity: 0 }}
                  whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                  key={index}
                >
                  <Todos text={i} key={index} />
                </motion.li>
              );
            })}
          </AnimatePresence>
        </motion.div>

variants
export const boxVariant = {
    hidden:{
        opacity:0
    },
    visible:{
        opacity:1,
        transition:{
            delay:0.7,
            when:"beforeChildren",
            staggerChildren:0.3
        }
    }
}

export const listVariant = {
    hidden:{
        x:-200,
        opacity:0,

    },
    visible:{
        x:0,
        opacity:1,
    }
}

I am trying to show the  component one by one but when i run, all the todos animate in same time without any delay in another  component. i tried previous one answers also but that is not working.
previous question => Framer-motion does not stagger children, no matter what I try

@AndrewYim Thanks for your response first of all. I tried that one also. i removed the delay in children and added the delayChildren in container but still not working.
